# Kernel of a differential operation from R to C0

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the $Ker(f)$ of the following differential function: $$y\mapsto y''+ay'+by$$ knowing that $a,b \in R$ and also that this function maps the following transformation: $$P_2 \rightarrow C^0 (R)$$ Where P2 is the vector space of all continuous polynomes over R of degree maximum 2.
I have to find $Ker(f)$ for different cases. The first example is using $a=-1, b=0$.
By doing so, I simply used the following variable switch: $y \rightarrow e^{\alpha x}$ which gives me: $$e^{\alpha x}(\alpha^2+a\alpha+b)=0$$ and $$e^{\alpha x}(\alpha^2-\alpha)=0$$ for my specific case. It's obvious the two roots are: $\alpha_1 =1$ and $\alpha_2 =0$. Now, from this result, I can find $Ker(f)$ using the general solution: $$\mathcal L=\{\lambda_0e^{\alpha_1 x},\lambda_1e^{\alpha_2 x}\}$$ Plugging in $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$: $$\mathcal L=\{\lambda_0e^{x},\lambda_1\}$$ I stopped there and thought that my solution is of the form: $$y=\lambda_0e^{x}+\lambda_1$$ for my specific conditions. I have also been told to take care about the definition range but I do not see where it could be a problem. Also, I do not know if I did enough or forgot/miswrote something about my problem. Would appreciate any input! Thank you.

Comment: When $y\to e^{\alpha x}$ is done it is not with the intention of changing variables. After all $y$ is a function of $x$ already. What is being done is trying a perticular family of functions to see which one could be a solution of the differential equation. The condition on $\alpha$ give you which of those are solutions. But in your case you need the solutions to be polynomials. So, the family that you should try is not $e^{\alpha x}$, but $rx^2+sx+t$.

Comment: Alright... That's a very pertinent remark and I thank you for that. I totally forgot about that... Maybe something else makes sense then... I am given three conditions (values of $a$ and $b$ for this exercise. I thought they were three different cases but if I take them together I can find the value for $r,s,t$ and solve the system for $rx^2+sx+t=0$! Does it make sense?

Comment: No, each given set of values of $a$ and $b$ should be separate problems. What you should expect to find is not specific values for $r,s,t$, but relations between them. For example, if you find that $s-t=0$. Then you know that the polynomials in the kernel are of the form $rx^2+sx+s$, which is a space of dimension $2$, generated by $x^2$ and $x+1$. You may find that in some cases the relations between $r,s,t$ is $r=s=t=0$. Then you know that the only polynomial in the kernel is $0$. Therefore the kernel would have dimension $0$ in that case.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the much appreciated help! Really helping a lot here. So if I follow you correctly, for values of $a=-1$ and $b=0$, I will get something like $y''-y'=0$, which (by using $rx^2+sx+t$) will be $2r(1-x)-s=0$. I can find the following relation: $2r(1-x)=s$. However, I am not sure this is enough.. Am I following the right path?

Comment: I have processed further with: finding the kernel polynomials of the form $rx^2+2rx(1-x)+t$ and then to $2rx-rx^2+t$ so a space of dimension 2 generated by $x^2$ and $x$. Am I following the right trail?

Comment: Note that a function $y=y(x)$ satisfies a differential equation, like $y''-y'=0$, when this is satisfied for all values of $x$. If you got the relation that for polynomials of degree at most $2$ this equation looks like $2r(1-x)-s=0$, then since this should hold for all $x$, you can conclude that $r=0$ and $s=0$. Therefore, only polynomials of the form $t$ are in the kernel of the differential operator, i.e. constant, belong to the kernel. So, the kernel has dimension $1$.

Comment: Ok! So now, I got it right! Let's say I have $a=0$ and $b=-1$ then my polynom becomes $y''-y=0$ following with $2r-rx^2-sx-t=0$ or $r(2-x^2)-sx-t=0$ The only way to have this $=0 \forall x$ is to have $r=s=t=0$, therefore my kernel has dimension 0 and the only polynom inside there is the 0 polynom.
Thank you very much for you precious help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the exercise properly.

You got $P_2:=\{ y(x)=\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma,\ \alpha , \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R} \}$, the space of polynomials with grade $\leq 2$, as domain of the differential linear operator $f: P_2 \to C^0(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:

$$f[y] := y^{\prime \prime} + a y^\prime + b y\; .$$

By definition, the *kernel* of $f$ is the subspace $\operatorname{Ker} f := \{ y(x) \in P_2:\ f[y(x)]=0 \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subseteq P_2$. Therefore, when you want to find the $\operatorname{Ker} f$ you have to look for *polynomials* $y(x)=\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ s.t.:

$$\tag{K} \forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad y^{\prime \prime} (x) + a y^\prime (x) + b y(x) = 0\; .$$

Since $y^\prime (x) = 2\alpha x + \beta$ and $y^{\prime \prime} (x) =2\alpha$, plugging $y$, $y^\prime$ and $y^{\prime \prime}$ in (K) yields you got to chose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in such a way that:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad 2\alpha + a (2\alpha x + \beta) + b (\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma)=0$$

or equivalently:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad b \alpha x^2 + (2a\alpha + b \beta) x +
(2\alpha + a \beta + b \gamma)=0$$

in order to have $y\in \operatorname{Ker}f$. *Identity Principle* yields $\alpha, \beta ,\gamma$ have to solve the system of linear equations:

$$\tag{S} \begin{cases} b\alpha = 0 \\ 2a\alpha + b \beta = 0 \\ 2\alpha + a \beta + b \gamma = 0 \end{cases}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad A\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{0}$$

with coefficents matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} b & 0 & 0 \\ 2a & b & 0 \\ 2 & a & b\end{pmatrix}\; .$$

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ system (S) is homogeneous therefore:

- either (S) has the unique solution $\alpha = \beta = \gamma =0$ when $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 3$,
- or it has $\infty^{3-r}$ solution, with $r:= \operatorname{rank}(A)$, when $\operatorname{rank}(A) < 3$.

Matrix $A$ contains two parameters, i.e. $a$ and $b$, therefore its rank may depend on how these two parameters are chosen; so you are led to the problem of finding $\operatorname{rank}(A)$. $A$ has rank $\geq 1$, for it has $2 \neq 0$ in the lower left corner; moreover it's easily seen that:

1. $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 1$ iff $a=b=0$,
2. $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$ iff $a\neq 0 = b$,
3. $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 3$ iff $b\neq 0$,

because $A$ is lower triangular and its nonzero diagonals have entries depending on only one parameter at the time.

Therefore, you have to split three cases to solve your exercise, namely:

1. $a=b=0$: in this case, your system (S) is equivalent to $\alpha = 0$, therefore the polynomials in $\operatorname{Ker}f$ are the ones of the type $y(x)=\beta x + \gamma$, i.e.:
   $$\operatorname{Ker}f = \{\beta x + \gamma,\ \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
   and $\dim \operatorname{Ker}f = 2$;
2. $a\neq 0 = b$: when this case occurs, (S) is equivalent to $\alpha =0 ,  \beta =0$, hence polynomials in $\operatorname{Ker}f$ are the ones of the type $y(x)= \gamma$, i.e.:
   $$\operatorname{Ker}f = \{\gamma,\ \gamma \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
   and $\dim \operatorname{Ker}f = 1$;
3. $a,b\neq 0$: this is the easiest case, for (S) is equivalent to $\alpha=0, \beta =0, \gamma =0$ and the only polynomial in $\operatorname{Ker}f$ is the null polynomial $y(x)=0$, i.e.:
   $$\operatorname{Ker}f = \{0\}$$
   and $\dim \operatorname{Ker}f = 0$.

P.S.: This exercise, although simple, gives an insight into the reasons why we need more than the *simplest functions* (i.e., polynomials) to *explictly* solve an ODE and why, during 17th to 19th centuries, mathematicians struggled to **define** all the *special functions* (exponentials, sine & cosine, logarithm, hyperbolic sine & cosine, etc...) needed to represent general solutions of many classes of ODEs. ;-)

Comment: Hi Pacciu, I thank you a lot for your dedication, time and patience to write this answer. I really appreciate and your insights helped me to great extend. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I’m here to help, when I can. ;-)